# If max timestamp is bigger than other max timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm still struggling making a menu with six links with images that differs depending on if a new record has ben added or not. I made a table which records the users clicks and the corresponding link_url and timestamp. I then want to compare the timestamp in the latest record in matningar containing the username and the matningstyp.

```
$query="SELECT max(click_timestamp) AS maxts FROM clicks WHERE username='$session->username' AND link_url='http://xxx/admin/amfmci.php'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$query1="SELECT max(datum) AS maxts FROM matningar WHERE kontakt='$session->username' AND matningstyp='bbb'";
$result1=mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
$line1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);

$senasteclick = $line['maxts'];
$senastematning = $line1['maxts'];

if ('$senasteclick' > '$senastematning'){
echo "<a href=\"http://xxx/admin/amf.php\"><img src=\"http://xxx/admin/images/emoikon3.png\" alt=\"Digg\" width=\"64\" height=\"63\"     border=\"0\"/></a>";  }
else {
echo "fail";
}
```

This does not work the way I want to. If I change the if statement to less than, the image changes.

If I change the date of record itself it does not change the image... So the code does not what I want it to do :(

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: That was a weird balance between english and swedish in your mysql tables! You can troubleshot this on your own without problems. Just `print_r($line);` and `print_r($line1);`

Comment: Another thing is your if statement, i don't think you want to have the `'` around your variables, ie: change it to: `if ($senasteclick > $senastematning) {`

Comment: Thanks guys for your input! Yep I have to get my head on straight and just one language! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query="
    SELECT max(c.click_timestamp) > max(m.datum) AS senas
    FROM clicks c
    inner join matningar m on c.username = m.kontakt
    WHERE 
        c.link_url='http://xxx/admin/amfmci.php'
        and
        m.matningstyp = 'bbb'
        and
        c.username = {$session->username}
";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$senas = $line['senas'];
if ($senas){
echo "<a href=\"http://xxx/admin/amf.php\"><img src=\"http://xxx/admin/images/emoikon3.png\" alt=\"Digg\" width=\"64\" height=\"63\"     border=\"0\"/></a>";  }
else {
echo "fail";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But how does this work?! If you could tell me something more about this solution I would really appreciate it! If not, thank you anyway for helping me out!!!! Cheers